# Android accelerometer values return back to zero, causing problems

Tags: android, accelerometer

here's my code:

```
      float x; 
      @Override
      public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    if(event.values[0] > .2){
        x = -1*(Math.round(event.values[0]));           
        centerx = centerx +(x*10);
    }

    else if(event.values[0] < -.2){
        x =  -1*Math.round(event.values[0]);
        centerx = centerx +(x*10);
    }
    mCustomDrawableView.invalidate();



    y = Math.round(event.values[1]);

    if(event.values[2] > .4){
        z = event.values[2];    
    }   

}
```

I'm using the accelerometer to move a vertical line back and forth. centerx is the top and bottom point of the vertical line. I'm trying to make it so if I move my device to the right, the line will move to the left and look like it's still in the same position, as if it were in the physical world (think of augmented reality).

I'm using the values given out of the SensorEvent to do some arithmetic to move center line. The only problem is that the accelerometer values will go up when I move the advice to something like 5, but then decrease to 4 to 3 to 2 to 1 to 0 as I stop moving. So, the line just kind of bounces to the side and then returns to the original center. I'm looking for a way to get rid of this "bounce," and have the line stay in it's new position. Any ideas?